# sequential processing for n number of times in jenkins pipline

Tags: jenkins, scripting, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline to do parallel processing like below

```
    buildNumber=[:]

    buildIterations.each{
        buildNumber[x]=createExecution(it)
    }
    node('MyJenkins'){
        stage{'Prepare database')
        --------
    }
    parallel buildNumber

    def createExecution(String number){
         cmd = { 
            node('MyJenkins'){
                stage('Build'){
                   ---------------------
                }
                stage('Test'){----------}
                stage('package'){--------}
             }
          return cmd
    }
```

But now i want to change this script to have sequential execution as this will run many builds in one job and have load on database at same time.

```
    //should be executed once
    node('MyJenkins'){
        stage{'Prepare database')
        --------
    }

    //should be executed one after the other, but below code isn't even considered for job. It just stops after prepare database
    buildIterations.each{
        number=it
        node('MyJenkins'){
                stage('Build'){
                   ---------------------
                }
                stage('Test'){----------}
                stage('package'){--------}
             }
    }
```

I am new to scripting, please help me know what mistake i am doing

Answer (score 0):

which versions of the pipeline plugins are you using? Earlier versions didn’t support iterating an object using `.each{}`. Sometimes this resulted in the behavior you described. An update of the groovy-cps plugin most probably will do. Version 2.33 is the absolute minimum. I‘d go for latest if possible.
See [groovy-cps plug-in](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-cps)
See also: [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-26481)